# C# EF Order by included table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to sort by a field on a child table of a one-to-many relation with C# and EF.

That's what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM Parent AS P
INNER JOIN Child AS C ON P.Id = C.PartentId
ORDER BY C.CreateDate
```

I guess the code should look something like this:

```
_context.Parent.Include(x => x.Child).OrderBy(x => x.Child.CreateDate)
```

This doesnt work since x.Child is a list of child objects. Is there a way to sort by children on the SQL server. I found many solutions but they order the list in the application.

Comment: So your output would be a list of parent, child tuples sorted by the child created date?

Comment: Assuming a `Child` has a `Parent` object along with the `ParentId` key, could you turn it around? `_context.Child.Include(c => c.Parent).OrderBy(c => c.CreateDate).Select(c => c.Parent).Distinct()`

Comment: ... or the given answer if you want {parent, child} tuples

Comment: see my comment in the accepted answer. thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `Join` or just `Select` like this:

```
_context.Child
  .Select(c => new {c.Parent, Child = c})
  .OrderBy(x => x.Child.CreateDate)
```

Comment: this is an old project that needed a fix. I wanted to change as little as possible. I ended up in rewrite the whole view and used a new view model. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Skuami NP. Gad if was able to help!